# Pass token from frontend to backend and access claims that can be used to filter data from database, React Django MySQL project

Tags: reactjs, django, token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

The map function in the Schools.js file shows all schools in the database. I want it to only fetch and display the shools where the dist_office_id = place_id and the school_name is not empty. the place_id is a claim in the token. I want to pass the token from the School.js file (frontend) to the views.py file (backend) where i need to access the place_id claim from the token. When i hardcode the place_id = 3 it works fine as expected but there are many district offices and it should only show schools under any district that the user may belong to.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import {Table, Button, ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {FaEdit} from 'react-icons/fa';
import {RiDeleteBin5Line} from 'react-icons/ri';
import {getSchools, deleteSchool} from '../services/SchoolService';
import AddSchoolModal from '../components/modals/api_modals/AddSchoolModal';
import UpdateSchoolModal from '../components/modals/api_modals/UpdateSchoolModal';


const Schools = () => {
    const [schools, setSchools] = useState([]);
    const [addModalShow, setAddModalShow] = useState(false);
    const [editModalShow, setEditModalShow] = useState(false);
    const [editSchool, setEditSchool] = useState([]);
    const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);

    const token = localStorage.getItem("authTokens")

    if (token){
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
        var place_id = decoded.place_id
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true;
        if(schools.length && !isUpdated) {
            return;
        }
        getSchools()
            .then(data => {
                if (mounted) {
                    setSchools(data);

                }
            })
            return () => {
                mounted = false;
                setIsUpdated(false);
            }
    }, [isUpdated,schools]);

    const handleAdd = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setAddModalShow(true);
    };

    const handleUpdate = (e, school) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setEditModalShow(true);
        setEditSchool(school);
    };

    const handleDelete = (e, id) => {
        if(window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            deleteSchool(id)
            .then((result) => {
                alert(result);
                setIsUpdated(true);
            },
            (error) => {
                alert("Failed to Delete!");
            })
        }

    };

    let AddModalClose = () => setAddModalShow(false);
    let EditModalClose = () => setEditModalShow(false);

     return (
        <div className="row side-row">
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>S/N</th>
              <th>School</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {schools.map((school, index) =>
                <tr key={school.id}>
                  <td>{index + 1}</td>
                  <td>{school.school_name}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button className='mr-2' variant="danger"  size="sm"
                        onClick={event => handleDelete(event,school.id)}>
                        <RiDeleteBin5Line />
                    </Button>
                    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <Button className='mr-2' variant="primary"  size="sm"
                        onClick={event => handleUpdate(event,school)}>
                        <FaEdit />
                    </Button>
                    <UpdateSchoolModal show={editModalShow} onHide={EditModalClose}
                    school={editSchool} setUpdated={setIsUpdated}>
                    </UpdateSchoolModal>
                  </td>
                </tr>)}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button variant="success" onClick={handleAdd}>Add School</Button>{' '}
            <AddSchoolModal show={addModalShow} onHide={AddModalClose} setUpdated={setIsUpdated}>
            </AddSchoolModal>
        </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
      );
};

export default Schools;
```

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function getSchools() {
    return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schools/")
    .then(response => response.data)
}
```

```
class SchoolView(APIView):
    def get_school(self, pk):
        try:
            school = Place.objects.get(id=pk)
            return school
        except Place.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404


    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            data = self.get_school(pk)
            serializer = PlaceSerializer(data)
        else:
            # Extract the place_id claim from the token
            place_id = 3

            # Check if place_id is not None before filtering
            if place_id is not None:
                data = Place.objects.filter(dist_office_id=place_id, school_name__isnull=False)
                serializer = PlaceSerializer(data, many=True)
            else:
                data = Place.objects.all()
                serializer = PlaceSerializer(data, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to access the token from the backend without passing it from the frontend. But for now i am now the place_id value i need as a parameter from the frontend but i think that is not safe.